# Is there a software to make old style maps for books?

Tags: maps

I'm looking for a software which can help me create similar maps as shown in the picture below. I want to make similar maps for a book. I want to know how maps in this layout/style are created?

[image: Map Smaple Image]

Comment: Do you have the source for this map ? What I mean where did you get it ?  Are you cartographer ?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I got the map samples from http://passia.org/maps/37. I'm a web developer. One of my clients wants me to make similar maps for his book supporting web application. Do you have an idea how such maps can be created ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked around  and your best bet is contact Professor Dr Kamal Abdul Fattah, He is a geographer on that site and you might ask him  for 1) copy a map , or you can ask him for his permission to get the layers or data he can provide you.  I don't know what kind of software he uses but there is a free software you can download  it is called QGIS .

Comment: BTW, you can download PDF or image from that site and you can keep the map but you will need to write a code for each layer on the map in the web application .